# How to navigate cursor with TabIndex by click on button in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button x:Name="BtnNavigateTabIndex" Content="NavigateTabIndex" Margin="152,200,0,190" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox_1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="120,64,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox_2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="120,128,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80"/>
    <PasswordBox x:Name="PasswordBox_1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="224,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72"/>
    <PasswordBox x:Name="PasswordBox_2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" Margin="224,128,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72"/>
</Grid>
```

The design will will be like below.

[image]

If i click the button(NavigateTabIndex),The cursor should be navigate to TextBox or PasswordBox.
For EX: If you click the Tab Key in you Keyboard,the cursor would navigate.This is the scenario what i need .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general there are a lot of gotchas with WPF focussing....some bugs even.

You need to understand the difference between Logical and Keyboard focus.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx

When using FocusScopes you can use:

`MoveFocus` with a `TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next)`

to change the logical focus to the next item in the scope.

An alternative to using FocusScopes is to track the GotFocus/LostFocus events and manage it yourself.

Some more links:

- [How to programmatically navigate WPF UI element tab stops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809382/how-to-programmatically-navigate-wpf-ui-element-tab-stops)
- [Move focus in response to keyboard events in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626830/move-focus-in-response-to-keyboard-events-in-xaml)
- [WPF FocusNavigationDirection, MoveFocus and Arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719116/wpf-focusnavigationdirection-movefocus-and-arrow-keys)
- [Locating the first WPF tab stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809622/locating-the-first-wpf-tab-stop)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38507/Using-the-WPF-FocusScope

---

Ok here's some example code for you. I took the liberty to redesign your use of the Grid a bit, to follow more conventional layout practice.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication5
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnNavigateTabIndex_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UIElement focussedelement = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(grid1) as UIElement;

            bool bmovedfocus = focussedelement.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));

            if (bmovedfocus)
            {
                UIElement withfocusnow = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(grid1) as UIElement;

                if (withfocusnow == focussedelement) // focus didn't change! because end of focus group..need to put it back to the start
                {
                    TextBox_1.Focus();
                }
            }
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox_1.Focus();
        }
    }
}


    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid x:Name="grid1" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBox Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="TextBox_1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80"/>
                <PasswordBox Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PasswordBox_1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72"/>
                <TextBox Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="TextBox_2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80"/>
                <PasswordBox Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PasswordBox_2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72"/>
                <Button FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" Padding="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="BtnNavigateTabIndex" Content="NavigateTabIndex"  Width="120" Click="BtnNavigateTabIndex_Click" />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Window>
```

Comment: I tried this code this.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next)); But it is not work.Please Post me the full program.It will much better.

Comment: I am in basic in stage in wpf.I can't get your point. if You post the full code, it will help me.

Comment: The above code is working well.Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score -1):

This line of code should set you in the right direction:

```
element.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

where element is a UIElement (like one of your textboxes). This is an excerpt from the following post: [Moving to next control on Enter keypress in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203329/moving-to-next-control-on-enter-keypress-in-wpf). And you put this code on the click event handler of the button...

By the way: discovering what the active UIElement / user control is can be done as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159719/wpf-equivalent-to-activecontrol).

Comment: i use this code element.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));. But it is not work...Please post me the full program.

Comment: Come'on ASHOKA a little more courage and effort to make this work. It's tooooo simple. I'm not gonna post the whole program :(